# How can I print a Binary Tree Search class Vertically?

Tags: c++

I've been learning how to program Binary Tree Search using Linked Lists in C++. Everything works fine and I understand how the Binary Tree works however I would like to be able to print the tree with the head on top and all the nodes following bellow as I try to demonstrate here:

```
                                     [root or head]
                            [left]                    [right]

                      [left]      [right]       [left]       [right]
```

I am using the Console to print the tree, therefore feel free to use 'cout' or 'printf'. I believe I need to set the width of the console but I'm not sure how to start.

Thanks, Y_Y

Comment: Y: what does the abstract-class tag have to do with your question? :)

Comment: If you want to do it in such a symmetrical fashion, you will need to know the depth and the length of the data you need to print _in advance_, in order to properly align the parent nodes. It might be easier to be content with a left-aligned output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As sbi mentioned, making a left-aligned version is easier than a center-aligned one.  But whichever alignment you choose your fundamental algorithmic approach should be:

Traverse the tree breadth-first.  Do this by using a queue with the following algorithm:

1. Declare a queue
2. Add the root node to the queue
3. While the queue contains more nodes, do 4 - 6:
4. Dequeue a node
5. Print the node.  After every print
   that is one less than a power of 2th time (starting from 1), also
   print a newline.
6. Enqueue the node's children

(See http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/ )

In order to print a center-aligned tree, also do the following (only works if the tree is complete.  If it's not complete, the easiest thing to do is make a complete copy where every place that should have a node gets some kind of a null node):

- Instead of printing to the screen,
  "print" each line into a string in
  an array of strings.
- As you go, keep track of the length
  in characters of the longest element
  you print.  Let's call this
  maxElemLen.
- Whenever you print an element, print
  one tab character before it and one
  tab character after it.
- At the very end, go back, and in
  every line in the array, replace
  each tab character with 2^(nLines -
  lineNum) tab characters.
- Then expand each tab that comes
  after a tab or newline to
  maxElemLen+1 spaces, and expand each
  tab that comes after anything else
  (i.e., after a printed elem) to (maxElemLen + 1 - (the
  number of characters elapsed since
  the last tab)) spaces.
- Finally, print each line of your
  array, in order.

Comment: Note that the part "After every print that is one less than a power of 2th time (starting from 0), also print a newline." is only correct if the tree is complete.  If it is not complete, you need a different way to keep track of when you have finished a level.

Comment: @Jon: What about the requited amount of spaces/tabs, which was the essential part of the question, i guess?

Comment: @Armen: Isn't that handled in the first sentence.

Comment: @sbi: yeah, after the edit, which happened 3 minutes ago, it is :)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan:  There ya go.  :-)

Comment: @Armen: From what i can see the first sentence never changed.

Comment: @Jon: Why are you repeating the first part? Did you accidentally mess this up or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jon: (It was me who made this comment.) From here it looks like your answer has three parts, the first two of which are identical.

Comment: @sbi  1) Whoops 2) Whoops.  Sorry Armen and thanks sbi.  It's 3:18 am here so I must have misread and mistyped.

Comment: I don't understand how to do step 5 from the first portion of the comment...? Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: @Y_Y:  Have a counter: `int oneMoreThanNNodesPrinted = 1`.  In your tree traversal: `print(thisNode); oneMoreThanNNodesPrinted++; int copy = oneMoreThanNNodesPrinted; while(!(copy & 1)) copy >> 1; if (copy == 1) print(newline);`

Comment: @Y_Y: Btw, I just fixed a bug in line 5 by changing "starting from 0" to "starting from 1".

Answer (score 3):

This is the code to print binary tree - below code prints binary tree from left to right fashion

```
private void printTree(Node nNode,int pos){
    if (nNode==null) {
        for(int i=0;i<pos;i++) System.out.print("\t");
        System.out.println("*");
        return;
    }
    printTree(nNode.right,pos+1);
    for(int i=0;i<pos;i++) System.out.print("\t");
    System.out.println(nNode.data);
    printTree(nNode.left,pos+1);
}
```

Here is the output of above method

[image]

'*' in above output indicates a null

Comment: So we tilt our head sideways to obtain the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

@IsAs's solution. 90 degree CCW rotated tree in C++. I advise this be used on trees no larger than 2^4.

```
print(root);
void BinarySearchTree::print(BinaryNode* n, int pos = 0){
    if (n==NULL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < pos; ++i)
            cout << "\t";
        cout << 'X' << endl;
        return;
    }
    print(n->right,pos+1);
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        cout << "\t";
    cout << n->key << endl;
    print(n->left,pos+1);
}
```